# Remove portion of Uri from slash onwards

Tags: c#, razor, uri

I am building a dynamic hreflang tag using a Uri from a string to extract the culture eg sometimes it might be **ru/about-us/** other times it might be **ru/** but what I need is to remove the part from the slash and just keep the culture part eg **ru**. I have been trying to solve this for few hours so can someone please point me in the the right direction, thank you.

```
  Uri hrefLang = new Uri(correctUrl, UriKind.Absolute);

 @Html.Raw(@"<link rel=""alternate"" href=""" + @correctUrl + @""" hreflang=""" + @hrefLang.LocalPath.Substring(1) + @"""/>" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `new Uri(correctUrl, UriKind.Absolute)` gives the full URI and you will always have a path starting with `/{culture}/` and you want a full URI which has only that segment of the path as the entire path.

If so then:

```
Uri fullUri = new Uri(correctUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
Uri hrefLang = new Uri(fullUri, fullUri.AbsolutePath.Substring(0, fullUri.AbsolutePath.IndexOf('/', 1) + 1));
```

will set `hrefLang` to be such a URI.